# How to pass props on react-redux component?

Tags: javascript, components, reduce

props aren't defined in my app is throwing an undefined error.
Once the state is defined, it doesn't rerender the component with the new props.

```
  render(){
    // console.log("RENDER PROPS", this.props)
    const  { name, category, price, img} = this.props

    return(
      <div>
        <h2>={name}/>
        <h4>{category}/>
        <h3>{price}</>
        <img={img}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the props through to your component. It's not very clear from the code you've show if/how you're doing this

Answer (score 0):

you should save props in inner state in the component see the example.

```
export default function Page({ nameFromProps , ageFromProps }) => {
    const [name , setName] = useState(nameFromProps );
    const [age, setAge] = useState(ageFromProps );
   useEffect(() => {
      setName(nameFromProps);
      setAge(ageFromProps);
   },[nameFromProps]);
  return (<div> Data : {name}{age} </div>)
}
```

Comment: The `OP` has used `render` method, so the component is a class component not function component

Comment: of course the code is in-class component but i described the method in functional component.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear that how you pass props to the component , maybe there is mistake in this step , but for check you can use

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.props.color !== nextProps.color) {
      return true;
    }
    if (this.state.count !== nextState.count) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

to check your props value and force to re render or not